# How to update column with rows values sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Can some one help me what is wrong with this code:

```
UPDATE tbl SET ('Name_AR') 
VALUES
('a'),
('b'),
('c');
```

Comment: What could you possibly be trying to accomplish?  This looks like a rather random collection of SQL keywords and identifiers.

Comment: [SQL UPDATE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: I need to update value in the column 'Name_AR'

Comment: In SQL, table rows are unordered. So you have to specify which value belongs into which row.

Answer (score 0):

Please review your syntax, might i suggest:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Not find a solution for my example